# getting garbage values in email

Tags: linux, sh

I have written a shell script which sends out an email once the process is done. 
So, when it send the email it also copy 10 last lines of a log file to that email but the issue is, it send some non-readable value to the email as shown below; even when we tail the log file it shows the readable format.

**E-mail text:::**

Maximum number of errors exceeded
 [H [2J [1;2H [K [2;2H [K [3;2H [K [4;2H [K [5;2H [K [6;2H [K [7;2H [K [8;2H [K [9;2H [K [10;2H [K [11;2H [K [12;2H [K [13;2H [K [14;2H [K [15;2H [K [16;2H [K [17;2H [K [18;2H [K [19;2H [K [1;29HRECORD LOADING STATISTICS [3;2HInput file  - vcc-bib-FINAL-201403      Start date - July 15 09:51PM [4;2HError file  - vcc-bib-FINAL-20140314.txt-REV.errlog      End date   - July 15 [5;2H09:51PM [6;2Hm2btab file - m2btab.batch [8;2HNumber of input records - 2501 [9;2HNumber of errors        - 5003 [11;21HNEW [11;49HEXISTING     INPUT     TOTAL [12;17HRECORDS      REC #S ASSIGNED     RECORDS   RECORDS   RECORDS [13;17HCREATED      START       STOP  OVERLAYED  REJECTED      READ [15;2HBibliographic        0 [15;56H0      2501      2501 [20;2H [K (0lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqk [21;2H [KxP > PRINT [21;43HC > marc tag COUNTS [21;79H (0x [22;2H [KxV > VIEW error file [22;43HQ > QUIT [22;79H (0x [23;2H [KxChoose one (P,V,C,Q) [23;7!
 9H (0x [24;2H [Kmqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj [23;24H [23;24H [23;2H [K (0xChoose one (P,V,C,Q) q [23;79H (0x [23;25H [23;25H

**Log file:::**

Maximum number of errors exceeded
                            RECORD LOADING STATISTICS

Input file  - vcc-bib-FINAL-201403      Start date - July 15 09:51PM
 Error file  - vcc-bib-FINAL-20140314.txt-REV.errlog      End date   - July 15
 09:51PM
 m2btab file - m2btab.batch

Number of input records - 2501
 Number of errors        - 5003

```
                NEW                         EXISTING     INPUT     TOTAL
            RECORDS      REC #S ASSIGNED     RECORDS   RECORDS   RECORDS
            CREATED      START       STOP  OVERLAYED  REJECTED      READ
```

Bibliographic        0                                0      2501      2501

lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqk
 xP > PRINT                               C > marc tag COUNTS                 x
 xV > VIEW error file                     Q > QUIT                            x
 xChoose one (P,V,C,Q) q                                                      x
 mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj
iii@vm-innovative (testapp-rSierra_2.0.1_5) 181 >

You may refer the "od" command result as below for the same log file if this helps to understand the issue..

iii@vm-innovative (testapp-rSierra_2.0.1_5) 184 > od nn.log

0000000 020012 031040 034464 020071 033040 032464 031465 020040
0000020 064123 071157 020164 072163 071157 062551 020163 067546
0000040 020162 072163 062165 067145 071564 020056 062533 020154
0000060 020040 042522 042512 052103 042105 020040 020040 020040
..
....

0002000 070561 070561 070561 070561 070561 070561 070561 070561
*
0002100 015553 031133 035461 044062 055433 074113 024033 050102
...
..
0002400 070561 070561 070561 070561 070561 070561 070561 070561
*
0002500 065161 024033 015502 031133 035463 032062 003510 055433
0002520 031462 031073 044064 055433 031462 031073 015510 045533

Please advise and let me know if somebody require that log file in an email/attachment.

Thanks,
Nitesh

Comment: Fix whatever is creating the log file so that it no longer contains cursor motion, color control, etc. escape sequences and code-page based line/box drawing characters.

Comment: Thanks Twalberg for taking a look. But the program which creates this log file is the Client's software and we have no right to make any changes in their program. But if I copy the last lone of log file in a notepad, it is fine there but when i send the content of that notepad into an email it comes with garbage value. Please let me know if you want that log file to check that, i can send that to you on your email id.